# where does the Node information in drupal database exist?

Tags: nodes, theming

I have a strange problem, Below are the steps I followed to create and delete a content type.

1. I have created a content type on site A.\
2. Deleted content type on Site A by navigating to structure->content types.
3. cleared cache.
4. Refreshed the content types page. What I saw was content type still existed.
5. deleted content type from 'node' and 'node_type' table in DB.
6. cleared the cache.
7. Refreshed the page. Still I see content type exist.
8. I checked the DB again, what I see is that node type re appears in DB.

Is there any other place where the node is getting populated from and making it to reappear?

Any suggestions/help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you install any module which re-create content-type when is not exists?

Comment: Nope I did not use any such modules

Comment: do you use features module?

Comment: Yes I use features module.

Comment: Features look for missed features and re create it, so disable related features.

Comment: content type that I created is not a feature, its just a node on a site.

Comment: Feature is a collection of things in Drupal, so it can contain a content-type.